# Is there any available features related to rerouting in HERE maps for javascript platform (or REST API)?

Tags: javascript, rest, here-api

I am not able to calculate a proper reroute when the user is deviating from the actual planned route. The user's heading direction is not considered when using the calculateRoute service.

I am trying to implement the rerouting feature by myself in javascript platform. At the beginning, I am calculating a route for the given start and destination geolocations/addresses.

If the user is deviating from the planned route, I am trying to reroute the user for which I have to calculate a new route to guide the user to the intended destination. I couldn't find any other method than using calculateRoute service to calculate the new route where I am stuck with the following problem.

i.e. Consider the following usecase where the user is supposed to take the first exit in a roundabout but a wrong exit is taken by mistake. With my rerouting logic, I am getting the confirmation that the user has deviated from the planned route and I am calculating the new route based on user's current location and the known destination point. The main problem that I am facing in this usecase is that the user is heading towards north but the calculated route instructs the user to take an illegal u-turn in order to reach the intended destination since the calculateRoute service doesn't consider the heading angle.

Please let me know if there is any other possible method to calculate a route for the proper rerouting in javascript/REST API platform.

Comment: Please refer routing API documentation 
developer.here.com/documentation/routing/topics/request-constructing.html
In case there is specific route example which works incorrectly, Can you please share the rest API URL

Answer (score 0):

Javascript/REST API or Routing API doesn't have possible like re-routing method because the Start/Destination Points are would to say always a stop-points therefore Routing API uses Start point as start to any directions to achieve cost optimized routing.

Your user always moves himself and has a trace of coordinates e.g. from the moment where you have deviated coordinate from the planned route then take deviated coordinates as additional waypoint (in a request: waypoint1=geo!passThrough!lat,lng) for your re-route and as start waypoint take please correct coordinate from user's trace that was before deviated. So you can avoid to take an illegal u-turn.